# Elementary Iwasawa module

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory, number-fields, iwasawa-theory

Let $k$ be a given number field. What is the importance and applications of knowing that the Iwasawa module $X_\infty$ of $k$ is an elementary $\Lambda$-module?

Comment: Nice question, Welcome to MO